# JUnit error: com.google.inject.CreationException: Guice creation errors

Tags: java, guice, junit4, xtext, xtend

I'm getting an error when trying to do unit testing of a DSL parser with Xtext and Xtend. I'm using com.google.inject.Inject and then I do a @Inject extension ParseHelper.

This is basically the error:

```
at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:435)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:154)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:106)
at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:95)
at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:72)
at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I am wondering how did you choose exactly these unrepresentative lines from the full stack-trace?

Comment: Seconding Oleg, Guice is often quite specific about its errors. Post your module code, and the entire exception text, and we might have enough to help.